# Convert a query producing XML so it produces JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml

I have a query (see below) which is used to create output as XML. The query deals with a matadata (EAV) system which has multiple column types and data.

I need to a version of this query to produce the output as JSON

I have already had a go, but hit problems.

1] I need to CAST the nvarchar(max) column data as nvarchar(4000) which is not ideal, something to do with the concatenation I think.

2] the XML and JSON column data is not correctly formatted to be valid JSON.

I haven't tried using OPENJSON or a CTE but willing to give anything a go.

I have a query in SQL Server 2017 (see below) which was used to create XMLdata and I need to change it to create results as JSON instead. Tried loads of things, but not quite able to get it. Appreciate any help.

Already have a query attempt for the JSON version but it has a few problems. 1] I need to CAST nvarchar as 4000 else it truncates data (not ideal).
2] Can't get the xml and json type columns to produce correct output.

Haven't tried using OPENJSON or CTE but open to ideas.

```
-- structure
    DECLARE @metaFields TABLE(
        [metaFieldID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
        [metasetID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [metaColumnID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [systemRef] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [displayType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
    )


    DECLARE @metaColumns TABLE (
        [metaColumnID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
        [storageTable] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [storageColumn] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [storageType] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [storageSize] [smallint] NULL
    )


    DECLARE @metaDataObjectVersions TABLE (
            [metaDataObjectVersionID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [xmlVersionData] [xml] NULL
    )


    DECLARE  @metaData TABLE (
        [metaDataID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [metaDataObjectVersionID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [metaColumnID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [numericData] [real] NULL,
        [dateData] [datetime] NULL,
        [textData] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [GUIDData] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [xmlData] [xml] NULL,
        [jsonData] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    )

    -- data
    INSERT INTO @metaFields
        ([metaFieldID],[metasetID],[metaColumnID],[systemRef],[displayType])
    VALUES
        ('FFFFFFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','AAAAAAAA-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','ACTIVE','RADIOBUTTON'),
        ('FFFFFFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000002','AAAAAAAA-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000002','CREATED','TEXT'),
        ('FFFFFFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000003','AAAAAAAA-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000003','CONTENT','TEXTAREA'),
        ('FFFFFFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000004','AAAAAAAA-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000004','TAGS','TEXT'),
        ('FFFFFFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000005','AAAAAAAA-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000005','XOPTIONS','SELECTBOX'),
        ('FFFFFFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000006','AAAAAAAA-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000006','JOPTIONS','SELECTBOX')

    INSERT INTO @metaColumns
        ([metaColumnID],[storageTable],[storageColumn],[storageType],[storageSize])
    VALUES
        ('CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000001','METADATA','numericData','numeric',NULL),
        ('CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000002','METADATA','dateData','date',NULL),
        ('CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000003','METADATA','textData','text',NULL),
        ('CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000004','METADATA','GUIDData','guid',NULL),
        ('CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000005','METADATA','xmlData','text',NULL),
        ('CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000006','METADATA','jsonData','text',NULL)

    INSERT INTO @metaDataObjectVersions
        ([metaDataObjectVersionID],[xmlVersionData])
    VALUES
        (1,'<data><active>1</active><created>2019-01-01</created><content>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt; HTML Document&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;HTML document&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</content><tags>37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2233,37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2244</tags><xoptions><rows><row id="37c3879f-cf6e-4a5d-bd3c-fcea1d9f2233"><optionValue>Usage 1</optionValue><sorting>1</sorting><selected>1</selected></row></rows></xoptions><joptions>[{"id": 1,"value": "Option 1","selected": true},{"id": 1,"value": "Option 1","selected": false }]</joptions></data>'),          
        (2,'<data><active>0</active><content>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt; HTML Document2&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;HTML document2&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</content><tags>37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F4433</tags><xoptions/><joptions>[{"id": 3,"value": "Option 3","selected": true}]</joptions></data>')          

    INSERT INTO @metaData
        ([metaDataID],[metaDataObjectVersionID],[metaColumnID],[numericData],[dateData],[textData],[GUIDData],[xmlData],[jsonData])
    VALUES
        (1,1,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000001',1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (2,1,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000002',NULL,'2019-01-01',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (3,1,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000003',NULL,NULL,'&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt; HTML Document&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;HTML document&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;',NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (4,1,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000004',NULL,NULL,NULL,'37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2233',NULL,NULL),
        (5,1,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000004',NULL,NULL,NULL,'37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2244',NULL,NULL),
        (6,1,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000005',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'&lt;rows&gt;&lt;row id=&quot;37c3879f-cf6e-4a5d-bd3c-fcea1d9f2233&quot;&gt;&lt;optionValue&gt;Usage 1&lt;/optionValue&gt;&lt;sorting&gt;1&lt;/sorting&gt;&lt;selected&gt;1&lt;/selected&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;/rows&gt;',NULL),--<rows><row id="37c3879f-cf6e-4a5d-bd3c-fcea1d9f2233"><optionValue>Usage 1</optionValue><sorting>1</sorting><selected>1</selected></row></rows>
        (7,1,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000006',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'[{"id": 1,"value": "Option 1","selected": true},{"id": 1,"value": "Option 1","selected": false }]'),
        (8,2,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000001',0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (9,2,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000003',NULL,NULL,'&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt; HTML Document2&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;HTML document2&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;',NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (10,2,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000004',NULL,NULL,NULL,'37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F4433',NULL,NULL),
        (11,2,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000005',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (12,2,'CCCCCCCC-0000-0000-0000-000000000006',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'[{"id": 3,"value": "Option 3","selected": true}]')

    -- EXISTING XML QUERY
    SELECT      metaDataObjectVersionID, 
                CAST(metaObjectVersionData AS XML) AS versionData
    FROM        (
                SELECT      MD.metaDataObjectVersionID,
                        (
                        SELECT          CAST('<' + LOWER(MF.systemRef) + '>' + LEFT(DATA.col, LEN(DATA.col) - 1) + '</' + LOWER(MF.systemRef) + '>' AS XML)
                        FROM            @metaData MD1 
                        INNER JOIN      @metaFields MF ON (MF.metaColumnID = MD1.metaColumnID) 
                        CROSS APPLY    (
                                        SELECT      CASE (SELECT MC.storageColumn FROM @metaColumns MC WHERE MC.metaColumnID = MD2.metaColumnID) 
                                                    WHEN 'numericData' THEN ISNULL(CAST(numericData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '') 
                                                    WHEN 'dateData' THEN ISNULL(CAST(dateData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '') 
                                                    WHEN 'textData' THEN ISNULL(CAST(textData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '')
                                                    WHEN 'guidData' THEN ISNULL(CAST(guidData AS VARCHAR(36)), '')  
                                                    WHEN 'xmlData' THEN ISNULL(CAST(xmlData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '') 
                                                    WHEN 'jsonData' THEN ISNULL(CAST(jsonData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '') 
                                                    ELSE CAST('' AS VARCHAR(36)) END + ','
                                        FROM        @metaData MD2
                                        WHERE       MD2.metaDataObjectVersionID = MD1.metaDataObjectVersionID AND MD2.metaColumnID = MD1.metaColumnID 
                                        FOR         XML PATH('')
                                        ) AS DATA(col)
                        WHERE           MD1.metaDataObjectVersionID = MD.metaDataObjectVersionID
                        GROUP BY        MF.systemRef, 
                                        DATA.col 
                        FOR             XML PATH(''), ROOT('data')
                        ) AS metaObjectVersionData
            FROM        @metaData MD
            GROUP BY    MD.metaDataObjectVersionID
            ) VW

-- JSON QUERY SO FAR
SELECT A.metaDataObjectVersionID, MDOV.xmlVersionData, N'{' + metaObjectVersionData + N'}'  AS JSONVersionData
FROM        (
            SELECT      MD.metaDataObjectVersionID,
                        (
                        SELECT          QUOTENAME(LOWER(MF.systemRef),'"') + ':' + LEFT(DATA.col, LEN(DATA.col))
                        FROM            @metaData MD1 
                        INNER JOIN      @metaFields MF ON (MF.metaColumnID = MD1.metaColumnID) 
                        CROSS APPLY    (
                                        SELECT     CASE (SELECT MC.storageColumn FROM @metaColumns MC WHERE MC.metaColumnID = MD2.metaColumnID) 
                                                        WHEN 'numericData' THEN CAST(numericData AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                                                        WHEN 'dateData' THEN  QUOTENAME(CAST(dateData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'"')
                                                        WHEN 'textData' THEN QUOTENAME(CAST(textData AS NVARCHAR(4000)),'"')
                                                        WHEN 'guidData' THEN QUOTENAME(CAST(guidData AS VARCHAR(36)),'"')
                                                        WHEN 'xmlData' THEN QUOTENAME(STRING_ESCAPE(CAST(xmlData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'json'),'"')
                                                        WHEN 'jsonData' THEN jsonData
                                                        ELSE CAST('' AS VARCHAR(36)) 
                                                    END + ','
                                        FROM        @metaData MD2
                                        WHERE       MD2.metaDataObjectVersionID = MD1.metaDataObjectVersionID AND MD2.metaColumnID = MD1.metaColumnID 
                                        FOR         XML PATH('')
                                        ) AS DATA(col)
                        WHERE           MD1.metaDataObjectVersionID = MD.metaDataObjectVersionID
                        GROUP BY        MF.systemRef, 
                                        DATA.col 
                        FOR             XML PATH('')

                        ) AS metaObjectVersionData
            FROM        @metaData MD
            GROUP BY    MD.metaDataObjectVersionID
            )    A              
JOIN        @metaDataObjectVersions MDOV ON A.metaDataObjectVersionID = MDOV.metaDataObjectVersionID
```

I would like the output to be correctly formatted and valid JSON. The correct expected format is below:

```
   {
  "active": 1,
  "content": "<html><head ><title> HTML Document</title></head><body><p>HTML document</p><a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com\">This is a link</a></body></html>",
  "created": "Jan  1 2019 12:00AM",
  "joptions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "Option 1",
      "selected": true
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "Option 1",
      "selected": false
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    "37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2233",
    "37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2244"
  ],
  "xoptions": "<rows><row id=\"37c3879f-cf6e-4a5d-bd3c-fcea1d9f2233\"><optionValue>Usage 1</optionValue> <sorting>1</sorting><selected>1</selected></row></rows>"
}
```

I have a working query now but seems a bit messy. If anyone can suggest improvements please comment.

```
--THIS IS THE QUERY WHICH SEEMS TO WORK!!!
SELECT      MDOV.metaDataObjectVersionID,
            '{' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(LOWER(MD1.systemRef),'"') + ' : ' + 
                CASE  
                    WHEN MD1.storageColumn = 'numericData' THEN CASE WHEN CNT > 1 THEN '[' + MD1.numericData + ']' ELSE MD1.numericData END
                    WHEN MD1.storageColumn = 'dateData' THEN CASE WHEN CNT > 1 THEN '[' + MD1.dateData + ']' ELSE MD1.dateData END
                    WHEN MD1.storageColumn = 'textData' THEN CASE WHEN CNT > 1 THEN '[' + MD1.textData + ']' ELSE MD1.textData END
                    WHEN MD1.storageColumn = 'guidData' THEN CASE WHEN CNT > 1 THEN '[' + MD1.guidData + ']' ELSE MD1.guidData END
                    WHEN MD1.storageColumn = 'xmlData' THEN CASE WHEN CNT > 1 THEN '[' + MD1.xmlData + ']' ELSE MD1.xmlData END
                    WHEN MD1.storageColumn = 'jsonData' THEN CASE WHEN CNT > 1 THEN '[' + MD1.jsonData + ']' ELSE MD1.jsonData END  
                END ,',') + '}'
FROM        @metaDataObjectVersions MDOV 
CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT      MD2.metaDataObjectVersionID,MF.systemRef,MD2.metaColumnID,MC.storageColumn,
                        COUNT(*) AS CNT,
                        STRING_AGG(CONVERT(VARCHAR,numericData), ',') AS numericData,
                        STRING_AGG('"' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateData,121) + '"', ',') AS dateData,
                        STRING_AGG('"' + CONVERT(CHAR(36),guidData) + '"', ',') AS guidData,
                        STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(textData, 'json') + '"', ',') AS textData,
                        STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),xmlData), 'json') + '"', ',') AS xmlData,
                        STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(jsonData, 'json') + '"', ',') AS jsonData
            FROM        @metaData MD2
            JOIN        @metaFields MF ON MD2.metaColumnID = MF.metaColumnID
            JOIN        @metaColumns MC ON MD2.metaColumnID = MC.metaColumnID
            WHERE       MD2.metaDataObjectVersionID = MDOV.metaDataObjectVersionID
            GROUP BY    MD2.metaDataObjectVersionID,MF.systemRef,MD2.metaColumnID,MC.storageColumn
            ) MD1
GROUP BY    MDOV.metaDataObjectVersionID
ORDER BY    MDOV.metaDataObjectVersionID
```

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2017, you have access to `FOR JSON`: [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). I suggest starting there. Please do give it a go first, and iof you get stuck show us your attempts, explain why they didn't work, and show what results you're after.

Comment: Already tried using FOR JSON but I just can't get it to work. The problem is that the data is stored vertically (hence the CROSS APPLY). Some columns have multiple rows of data so need to be converted to JSON arrays etc. Please take a look at the queries I've provided and you should be able to see what I mean.

Comment: I can't see any references to `FOR JSON` in your post to look over? Perhaps you forgott to paste that specific code? See my previous comment on what we need.

Comment: I have attempted to use FOR JSON but I just couldn't get it to work, I can try and find my previous attempt but not sure its much use as it doesn't work. You can't just sub out FOR XML for FOR JSON as there are differences which mean the query has to change significantly and that's the point i'm stuck at.

Comment: Please do post your attempt, and show us the expected result you're after.

Comment: To be honest: I think your data model is really weird. In `@metaData` you try to store a generic EAV-structure in a kind of *type-safe* manner. But at least the XML value is not re-escaped. The most important question is: Is the set of `systemRef` values fix? In this case you might create a *all-and-everything* approach for any possible value here. Otherwise the whole thing will have to be created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I've invested some time, but there are multiple problems. Please add some details to your question:

The XML-escaping is really weird, Will the XML typed column be a string with escape sequences or real XML? The most difficult part is the column naming. XML and JSON need to know these names in advance. You use the trick with `CAST('<' + SomeName + '>' AS XML)`, which can be a workaround, but you open the door to hell with this...

Your own query introduces a huge problem here. You get something like

```
<content>&amp;lt;html&amp;gt;&amp;lt;head&amp...
```

Do you really want to store a **string XML** within XML???

Another problem, when you try to use casting between XML, string and JSON is the type of quotes. The double quotes cannot be used within JSON directly (need to be escaped), but XML would do well with single quotes too... That will need a lot of `IF/CASE`...

There are some tags with multiple array values (like `"tags":[Val1,Val2]`), which is not supported by `FOR JSON`.

At least, I'm pretty sure, your query can be simplified. Try this:

```
SELECT ov.metaDataObjectVersionID
      ,(
            SELECT CAST(
                    CONCAT('<'
                           ,LOWER(MF.systemRef)
                           ,'>'
                           ,(SELECT 
                            CONCAT(numericData
                                  ,dateData
                                  ,CAST(textData AS XML).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                  ,GUIDData
                                  ,xmlData.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                  ,jsonData
                                  ,'') FOR XML PATH(''))
                           ,'</'
                           ,LOWER(MF.systemRef)
                           ,'>') AS XML)
            FROM            @metaData MD1 
            INNER JOIN      @metaFields MF ON (MF.metaColumnID = MD1.metaColumnID) 
            WHERE           MD1.metaDataObjectVersionID = ov.metaDataObjectVersionID
            FOR             XML PATH(''), ROOT('data'),TYPE
        ) AS metaObjectVersionDataXML
FROM        @metaDataObjectVersions ov;
```

The result for `metaDataObjectVersionID=1`

```
<data>
  <active>1</active>
  <created>Jan  1 2019 12:00AM</created>
  <content>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt; HTML Document&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;HTML document&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</content>
  <tags>37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2233</tags>
  <tags>37C3879F-CF6E-4A5D-BD3C-FCEA1D9F2244</tags>
  <xoptions>&lt;rows&gt;&lt;row id="37c3879f-cf6e-4a5d-bd3c-fcea1d9f2233"&gt;&lt;optionValue&gt;Usage 1&lt;/optionValue&gt;&lt;sorting&gt;1&lt;/sorting&gt;&lt;selected&gt;1&lt;/selected&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;/rows&gt;</xoptions>
  <joptions>[{"id": 1,"value": "Option 1","selected": true},{"id": 1,"value": "Option 1","selected": false }]</joptions>
</data>
```

Well, the `tags` don't look as you need them, but this can be solved...

I'd try to create the JSON out of the native XML with XQuery/FLWOR statements, but before I can try to do more, I ask you to answer my questions.